# Wicket Web Sockets cannot work with multiple browser windows

Tags: websocket, wicket

I created a Web-Socket application in Wicket having a server that pushes messages to all clients. After registrating the clients (application, sessionId and Key (PageId)) the server pushes the messages. So far so good. But if I have multiple browser windows of the same browser on the same client, only one window receives the message and processes it.

Do all browser windows (of the same browser) share the same sessionId? If yes, is there a way to differ between them?

Answer (score 0):

All browsers (from the same vendor, e.g. Firefox) will share the same session id. But if the page id is different then there will be separate web socket registrations and all of them will have their own connection, i.e. all of them will be able to send/receive messages.

If you need to be notified by Wicket when the user opens a second tab/window for the same page id then use `org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxNewWindowNotifyingBehavior` on the page. Most probably you will want to use `setResponsePage(page.getClass())` to create a new instance of the same page and have a new WebSocket connection for it.

Comment: Hi, I am strugling with the same problem. Your proposed solution has one problem - page for a new tab is rendered - new websocket connection is established (and it overwrites previous connection in the connection registry) and after this you are notified that this is a new tab. But you have already lost the reference to the previous connection. Any ideas?

Comment: I have tried `RequestCycleListener` that checks in `onRequestHandlerResolved` whether the handler is `RenderPageRequestHandler` of an existing page instance that has open websocket connection. And if so it is replaced with a new handler for a new page. This works pretty good, but I can't distinguish between new tab and refresh of current tab.